# Mule-EE windows service not starting

Tags: mule

I was trying to start the **mule mmc and mule-ee using the start launcher** given in the mule mmc distribution package. When Ia m running the **start.bat** it was mentioning that the mule instance is already running. 
When i checked the windows process I was not able to see any related java process running and in services I could see mul-ee in stopped state. When I am trying to start the mule-ee service it is mentioning that the **file path cannot be identified.**

I even tried to remove the service which also was not possible.

Could you please help in finding what might be issue ?.

Regards
Arun

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue temporarily by deleting the mule-ee service.

**Below is the command used :**
sc delete mule-ee

Regards
Arun

Answer (score 0):

Same issue occur to me also, I find the port which running for mule instance, I have killed it and run start.bat file.. I am not sure about mule-ee is the problem.

I might guess that your are not stopped your mule and mmc instance while shoutdown the pc.

Comment: There was no process instance of mule and ensured that there was no associated port also listening. But saw that mule-ee service was in stopped state and not getting removed. Once it was removed things got resolved.